# create multiple runtime textview in android

Tags: android, eclipse, textview, runtime, tablerow

I have code in eclipse for create multiple `TextView` in multiple rows but when run the application items don't show, please help me how to fix it.

This is my code:

```
public void createInputBoxes(Activity gameplay, int colnums, int rownums, TableLayout.LayoutParams lparams, TableLayout puzzlelayout) {

    TextView[][] puzcels = new TextView[colnums][];
    puzzlelayout.removeAllViews();

    for(int c=0; c<colnums; c++)
    {
        puzcels[c]=new TextView[rownums];
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(gameplay);
        tr.setLayoutParams(lparams);

        for(int r=0; r<rownums; r++)
        {
            puzcels[c][r] = new TextView(gameplay);
            puzcels[c][r].setLayoutParams( lparams);
            puzcels[c][r].setId(tvid);
            puzcels[c][r].setText("?");
            tvid++;
            puzcels[c][r].setBackgroundColor(0xffffb90f);
            tr.addView(puzcels[c][r]);

        }
        puzzlelayout.addView(tr,lparams);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `TableLayout.LayoutParams` params for all of your views - `TableLayout`, `TableRow` and `TextView`. That won't work for those last two. You need to give them params that work for them:

[Dynamically filling a Table Layout with Table Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580742/dynamically-filling-a-table-layout-with-table-rows)